# 1 help, undefined index when retrieving a GET variable

Tags: php, get

I am trying to retrieve the $_GET variable but it keeps telling me that I have an undefined index as if the variable wasn't stored.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="commentEdit.php" method="post">
        <label for="content">Content:</label>           
        <input type="text" id="content" name="content" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="reset" name="reset"/>
    </form>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","forum_db");
            if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Error: Could not connect to database.Please try again later";
            exit;
        }           

        $comment = $_POST['content'];
        $comment_id = $_GET['commentID'];
        $commentUpdate = "UPDATE tbl_comments SET forum_comment='$comment' WHERE forum_commentID='$comment_id'"; 

        $commentUpdate_result = mysqli_query($connection, $commentUpdate)
            or die ("Error is query:".mysqli_error($connection));
    }


?>
```

Comment: Well do you have it defined?In your url do you have something like something?commentID=blah

Comment: Yes, when I tried doing tests by opening another php script ontop of it and removing it from the bottom script I get the number I want, but when I try to use it on the bottom script it tells me it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is no $_GET variable after submitting your form. It shoul look something like this:

```
<form action="commentEdit.php?commentID=<?php echo $commentId; ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to user `$_REQUEST` variable which is handle both `$_GET ,$_POST` variable